# Kibana openshift access with no login

Tags: openshift, kibana

I have a Kibana instance conifigured with the Openshift operator Cluster logging. But now only the people who have access to Openshift are able to see the logs. How do i configure Kibana with a local test user and not the cloud login?

In the Kibana pod yaml I do not see any information where the users are configured. How is it possible to make Kibana open with a local test user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Redhat operator Cluster logging, the login cannot be disabled as it is part of the Redhat Kibana image.